# SphinxQL - what means comma in MATCH query

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxql

my question is:

what is the mining of the following matching parts of query (SphinxQL):

```
1. MATCH('php, programmer')

2. MATCH('php,programmer')

3. MATCH('php programmer')
```

And what is the difference in meaning of this query when using PHP SphinxAPI.

Thx for any advice 
I did`nt find anything useful in docs - maybe I have been looking in wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing that would affect this is charset table

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table

That will decide if comma is a seperator or a word charactor.

Comment: And if it is configured as separator?

Comment: if a seperator, all tho three queries would be identical. Imagine just replacing the comma with a space. multiple sperators count as one.